Нow to add a vertical scrollbar to non-executable code?
I have a chunk of code in a language, say Matlab, that has no engine installed in Quarto.
The chunk is only shown for illustration purposes, but it is valid code and can be used, highlighted etc.
So I cannot do something like  ```{matlab}. For this scenario there are some workarounds with css styles.
However, I can do just  ```matlab.
Now, my question is how to control code chunk overflow by height in this case?
All I need is a scrollbar by height (by width it works automatically).

If you provide code via  ```matlab, then this code gets rendered inside a <code> element which has the classes sourceCode and matlab. Hence, you can apply css on the selector .sourceCode .matlab, e.g. a suitable adjustment of max-height and overflow-y yields a horizontal scroll bar.
document.qmd
---
title: Code chunk height scrollbar
format: 
  html:
    css: styles.css
---

## Matlab

```matlab
clear;

v = [1, 4, 7, 2, 19];

maximum = v(1);

for i = 1:length(v)
    element = v(i);
    
    if element > maximum
        maximum = element; 
    end
end

disp('The maximum is: ');
disp(maximum);
```

styles.css
.sourceCode .matlab {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}



thanks, great! By the way, where do you look for those styles? In source code for html, or is there some references for default classes?

Yes, I often look into the HTML source code. For some topics there is also a good documentation available, e.g. HTML theming.
